# html, canvas, drawing line while animate() of jQuery: I dont want it to be persistent

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Lets see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2swQ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#a').animate({
        left: 100,
        top: 50
    },
    {
        duration: 2000,
        step: function (now) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo (0, 0);
            context.strokeStyle = '#ffff00';
            context.lineTo ($(this).position().left, $(this).position().top);
            context.stroke();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#a').animate({
                left: 100,
                top: 0
            },
            {
                duration: 1000,
                step: function (now) {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo (0, 0);
                    context.strokeStyle = '#ffff00';
                    context.lineTo ($(this).position().left, $(this).position().top);
                    context.stroke();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

here you can see a moving div, always followed by a line. But in the end, I got a filled triangle - I dont want it, I dont want to be that line persistent. So the previous line should be removed when a new is drawn - it other words, nullify the previous line.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas for  each draw. Add this to the bunch before you draw the line:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
```

And **[it will work](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Z2swQ/3/)**.